# Hyphenation for Chinese pinyin

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia, chinese, pinyin

Using XeLaTeX with polyglossia, I’m typesetting a document that includes Chinese pinyin: not the whole text, but still a fair bit, so I want to avoid manually providing rules for hyphenation.

Unfortunately, polyglossia doesn’t seem to offer Chinese pinyin support.
Is there a package that provides pinyin hyphenation (maybe triggered by a command like `\pinyin{text in pinyin}`)?

The documentation of the `xeCJK` package (which I use) doesn’t say anything about pinyin, and the `xpinyin` package seems to do something different altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum, the `polyglossia` hook seems to be broken. You probably want to file a bug report at [tex-hyphen](https://github.com/hyphenation/tex-hyphen).

The `babel` version works for `pdfTeX`.

According to the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyph-utf8?lang=en), you should be able to bypass `polyglossia` in `XeLaTeX` by directly using the low-level command, and it appears the following code, which you can build using `xelatex`, works (gives the same output as `pdflatex` with `babel`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\pinyin[1]{\begingroup \language=\l@pinyin #1\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{8em}
Woshi zhongguoren. Wo bushi beijingren. 
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{8em}
    \pinyin{Woshi zhongguoren. Wo bushi beijingren. }
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]